# where I'm wrong in calculating Residue at $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

Im looking at the function $f(z) = \dfrac{e^z}{z}$. trying to calculate integral on , say, $|z| = 1$. the answer is $2\pi i*res(f,0) = 2\pi i$

so far, so good, but , when I try to calculate the integral using $-2\pi i*res(f,\infty)$ I get wrong answer, because , when I try to calculate the Residue i get $-1/2$ (and not $-1$ as expected). because when I develop $f(1/z)$ around $0$, I get $f(1/z) = z*e^{1/z} = z*\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{-n}}{n!} = ... +1/2*\dfrac{1}{z}+ ...$ so by definition $res(f,\infty) = -1/2$.

what I'm missing here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To take the [residue at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity), you consider 
$$-\frac{1}{z^2}f\left( \frac{1}{z}\right).$$

So in fact we should be considering the residue at $0$ of
$$-\frac{1}{z^2}  \cdot z e^{1/z} = -\frac{1}{z}e^{1/z},$$
which has residue $-1$, as desired.

Comment: thanks. I was wrong in the definition. just confused.

Answer (score 0):

in general, if $z_0$ be a singular point of function f and also be of order m, the residue value can be derived as follow:

$
Res(z=0)=\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}{(m-1)!}  \frac{d^m-1}{dz^{m-1}}   ((z-z_0)^mf(z))
$

Therefore, in case of our question we will have:

$
Res(z=0)=\lim_{z \to 0} e^z = 1
$

Comment: the formula, is based on the McLaurin series expansion.